# A doubt on solving a problem involving residues

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, analytic-functions

Let $D=\{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|<2\}$ and $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a complex-valued function such that $f$ is analytic at all points of $D$ except a simple pole at $z=1.$ Given that $f$ has series expansion
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n z^n , |z|<1.$$
Show that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} a_n=-c,$$
where $c$ is the residue of $f$ at $z=1.$

$\textbf{My attempt:}$
From the given details, we can write $f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{z-1},$ where $g(z)$ is analytic in whole of $D.$
Now we have that $$Res(f,1)=c=\lim_{z \rightarrow1}\bigg((z-1)\frac{g(z)}{z-1}\bigg)=g(1).$$
Also, we can write $$f(z)=-g(z)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n, |z|<1.$$

I'm stuck here and not able to proceed.
Any hints would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: $f(z)-\frac{c}{z-1}=f(z)+\frac{c}{1-z}$ Must be analytic on $D$. Thus its seroes at $z=0$, which is $\sum_n(a_n+c)z^n$ must be analytic on $D$. In particular, its coefficients tend to zero.

Comment: NDB means "Thus its series at $z=0$".

Comment: Same is the case for $f(z)-\frac{c^2}{z-1},$ i.e.,  $f(z)-\frac{c^2}{z-1}$ is analytic in D. But this implies $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = -c^2.$$ Am I missing something ??

Comment: No, $f(z)-\frac{c^2}{z-1}$ is still singular at $z=1$, unless $c=1$. You can check the particular example of $f(z)=\frac{c}{z-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(z) = (z-1)f(z)$, $g$ is analytic on $D$ and the residue of $f$ at $z=1$ is $g(1)$. Let $g(z) = g_0+g_1z+g_2z^2+...$ be the expansion of $g$ around $z=0$. Note that $g(1) = g_0+g_1+...$. Let $r \in (0,1)$ and let $C$ be the circle of radius $r$ about $z=0$. Then
$a_n = {1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_C {g(z) \over z^{n+1} (z-1) } dz = -\sum_k {1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_C {g(z) \over z^{n+1} } z^k dz = - \sum_{k=0}^n g_k$ and so $a_n \to -g(1)$.